# I tried to follow the instruction in building tailwindcss (output.css) but the generate css file is missing some classes

Tags: tailwind-css

I have followed the instructions written in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation,but the generated css i.e output.css appears to have incomplete classes. background colors, block and divide classes aren't generated and others. I have tried updating my nodejs,node,npm but it is still generating incomplete classes.

Can you please shed a light on this?

Regards,

Leo

Answer (score 0):

It could be that that tailwind dont know which files he have to watch.

For Example. watch all html and js files inside ./src/
`module.exports = {  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],`

Change the path so that all files of your project are included.

Comment: I am getting three
Unknown at rule @tailwind
and issue in package.json
$ref '/definitions/variables' in 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults' can not be resolved.